# Why is this code printing aa0 as an element in set although aa is not a substring of ab?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, slice, prefix

**strong text**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<set>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main() 
{
     long int t;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--)
    {
        string s1,s2,x,a,b,f;
        cin>>s1>>s2>>x;
        std::set<string> s;
        int n,m,A;
        n=s1.length();
        m=s2.length();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a=s1.substr(0,i+1);
            if(boost::algorithm::contains(x, a));
            {
                s.insert(a+"0");
            }
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                b=s2.substr(0,j+1);
                if(boost::algorithm::contains(x,b))
                {
                    s.insert("0"+b);
                }
                f=a+b;
                if(boost::algorithm::contains(x,f))
                {
                    s.insert(f);
                }
            }
           
        }
        cout<<(s.size())+1<<endl;
            for (auto it = s.begin(); it !=
                             s.end(); ++it)
        cout << endl << *it;
    /*A=boost::algorithm::contains(x,"aa0");
        cout<<A;*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Given 3 strings S1, S2 and X, find the number of distinct ordered pairs of strings (P,Q) such that :

String P+Q is a substring of X.

String P is some prefix of S1 (possibly empty).

String Q is some prefix of S2 (possibly empty).

A substring of a string is a contiguous subsequence of that string. For example, "chef" is a substring of "codechef", but "def" is not. Also, an empty string is a substring of any string.

A prefix of a string S is a substring of S that occurs at the beginning of S. For example, "code" is a prefix of "codechef", but "chef" is not. Also, an empty string is a prefix of any string.**

**My approach-slicing the string s1 and s2 using substr function and then checking whether there are substring of x using a algorithm or boost function
**i have used s.insert(a+"0") it just signifies that a is a prefix of s1 string and we have taken null prefix i.e. ""  from s2. Same s.insert(""+b) means null prefix from string s1 and b prefix from s2 and so on.**

****Problem - It is giving wrong output for one inputset dont know why. Debug it and see the pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUm5O.png **

Comment: It is giving right output for other cases. However for this case I cant code behavior.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` **and** other includes from the Standard Library indicates that you are copy/pasting code without knowing what it actually does. The advice you'll get from this site is to [NOT use bits/stdc++.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). You should also [not include `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I have just checking various efficient substring checking methods.I have put using namespace std after the function so std::

Comment: What you are "just" doing is writing unreadable and nigh un-debuggable code. Use proper variable names, for a start. The goal of writing code is to do so in a way that is human-readable.

Comment: Anyone here who is going to try to help you already knows what `using namespace std;` does. And they will still tell you not to do it. I've edited my earlier comment with links as to why two lines of your code in particular are terrible practice.

Comment: Actually usually I dont write Code in C++. I write code in Python3 Since it is giving TLE.I have switched language to C++.

Comment: @AbhishekSanwal I think that when you encountered an TLE(Time Limite Exceeded), usually your implementation is slow, not the language you're using.

Comment: To be more specific, you're using the wrong algorithm. Substring stuff usually involves a sliding window.

Comment: Yes I agree to you at some extent .But currently no other approach in my mind regarding this ques.

Comment: Add link of the algorithm that i should use. and kindly find error in this program

Comment: i have used s.insert(a+"0") it just signifies that a is a prefix of s1 string and we have taken null prefix i.e. ""  from s2. Same s.insert(""+b) means null prefix from string s1 and b prefix from s2 and so on.

Comment: "Add link of the algorithm that i should use." No. That's not how this site works. Please read [ask] and [mre], and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your main function a little and removed boost usage (since you don't really need it here). I've also removed your namespace declarations as that is a bad idea. Lastly, I replaced your boost usage with a simple string::find. You can find the live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Grc9efxKn).

The output is :

```
4

0b
a0
ab
```

The updated main() is below with your example set, instead of using std::cin.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
     long int t{1};
     while(t--)
    {
        std::string s1{"aa"},s2{"bb"},x{"ab"},a{""},b{""},f{""};
        std::set<std::string> s;
        int n,m,A;
        n=s1.length();
        m=s2.length();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a=s1.substr(0,i+1);
            if(x.find(a) != std::string::npos)
            {
                s.insert(a+"0");
            }
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                b=s2.substr(0,j+1);
                if(x.find(b) != std::string::npos)
                {
                    s.insert("0"+b);
                }
                f=a+b;
                if(x.find(f) != std::string::npos)
                {
                    s.insert(f);
                }
            }
           
        }
        std::cout<<(s.size())+1<<std::endl;
            for (auto it = s.begin(); it !=
                             s.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << std::endl << *it;
    /*A=boost::algorithm::contains(x,"aa0");
        cout<<A;*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```